# How to clear browser console from angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Can I clear browser's console from angularjs controller.While posting password and username from client side to server via $http showing in the console.I need to get rid of it.Please help and thanks in advance.I have already asked this one ,but I didn't get any solution.

Answer (score 4):

This should do,

```
console.clear()
```